# In a Record Triggered Flow if the same record which triggered the flow is updated will the flow run into a recursive flow

Tags: visual-workflow, recordtriggeredflow

Whenever a record triggered flow updates the same record which triggered the flow will the flow keep getting triggered in recursive manner

Answer (score 2):

No. Salesforce doesn't fire Flows on a recursive save. Any direct updates to the record triggering the flow should be done in a before-save Flow in any case. Workflow updates can trigger a single recursive save that fires record validation and update triggers, but after-save flow doesn't. Because all DML actions are committed to the database at the end of a transaction, even if a Flow creates or updates another record that impacts the firing record, it won't recurse through the save actions. There's a great flow chart [here](https://architect.salesforce.com/1/asset/immutable/s/e6cf2ac/assets/images/Salesforce-Order-Of-Execution-Diagram.png). See in particular the recursive save decision between steps 8 & 9, and step 11a, which is the workflow partial recursive save, and happens before any after-save flows are run.